# String.format() adding 2 blank spaces when arguments are empty strings

Tags: java, string, format, whitespace

I have this simple method that goes:

```
private String toJsonFormat(String name, Object value, boolean first) {
    value = value == null ? "" : value; 
    return String.format((first ? "" : ",") + "\"%1s\":\"%2s\"", name, value);
}
```

When my *value* argument is `null`, 2 blank spaces are added after the colon, instead of an empty string.

An example return value when `null` is passed:

```
"housenumber":"  "
```

How come?

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Also, unless the `first` part is really required to demonstrate the issue, you should remove that part of it. An ideal question for a problem like this contains a short but complete program with *nothing* but the issue at hand, along with a description of the expected and actual results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The format specifier

```
%2s
```

means that this field will be at least two characters wide, space-padded as necessary.

If what you meant is "the second string", then just write

```
%s
```

This will automatically give you the second argument because it is the second specifier you use. Same for `%1s` you have for the first argument.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I thought it had something to do with the order of the arguments :\